# Ansible: Unique Shortest Paths

Tags: list, filter, ansible, jinja2

### Context

I have a list of files and directories to be deleted.
This is obtained from lines starting with the word "deleting" from an rsync stdout.

```
rsync stdout_lines: [
    "building file list ... done",
    "*deleting   Lab02/Ex2/Doc1.txt",
    "*deleting   Lab02/Ex2/",
    "*deleting   Lab02/Ex1/Doc1.txt",
    "*deleting   Lab02/Ex1/",
    "*deleting   Lab02/",
    ".d..t...... ./",
    "*deleting   Lab01/Ex2/Doc1.txt",
    "*deleting   Lab01/Ex2/",
    "*deleting   Lab01/Ex1/Doc2.txt",
    "*deleting   Lab01/Ex1/Doc1.txt",
    ".d..t...... Lab01/",
    ".d..t...... Lab01/Ex1/",
    "sent 350 bytes  received 191 bytes  360.67 bytes/sec",
    "total size is 614  speedup is 1.13 (DRY RUN)"
]
```

Formatted using:

```
'{{ sync_return.stdout_lines | select("regex", "^[*]deleting") | map("regex_replace", "^[*]deleting", "") | map("regex_replace", " ", "") | list }}'
```

A primitive example of the format of this list is as follows:

```
formatted list: [
    "Lab02/Ex2/Doc1.txt",
    "Lab02/Ex2/",
    "Lab02/Ex1/Doc1.txt",
    "Lab02/Ex1/",
    "Lab02/",
    "Lab01/Ex2/Doc1.txt",
    "Lab01/Ex2/",
    "Lab01/Ex1/Doc2.txt",
    "Lab01/Ex1/Doc1.txt"
]
```

In an attempt to hasten the process of deleting (by reducing the number of elements to iterate over) - I separated the list into 2 sub-lists:

- A list of directories. (elements of the main list that end in '/')

  '{{ items_to_delete | select("regex", "/$") | list }}'
- A list of file paths. (elements who's containing directory does not get deleted)

  '{{ items_to_delete | reject("match", item) | list }}'

The sub-lists for the example above would be...

```
directories to delete: [
    "Lab02/Ex2/",
    "Lab02/Ex1/",
    "Lab02/",
    "Lab01/Ex2/"
]

files to delete: [
    "Lab01/Ex1/Doc2.txt",
    "Lab01/Ex1/Doc1.txt"
]
```

### The Problem

Whilst the current solution works, it's not the best it could be. The dream is to have a solution where the "directories to delete" list only contains the highest level directories possible. i.e. Since we know the directory "Lab02/" is being deleted, "directories to delete" will NOT contain "Lab02/Ex2/" or "Lab02/Ex1/".
I believe my goal is somewhat similar to the os.path.commonprefix python function, however must be done for a variety of file paths within the list.

I'm relatively new to Ansible, so any guidance/help with this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't ask why you want to implement that, and I'll take it as an exercise.

Idea is, you can sort directories alphabetically, then while looping the paths, you strip any one that starts with the previous line.

You can write your filter like this (put in `filter_plugins` directory):

```
def common_paths(paths=[]):
    sorted_paths = sorted(paths)
    pfx = sorted_paths[0]
    for path in sorted_paths[1:]:
      if re.compile("^%s.*" % pfx).match(path):
         sorted_paths.remove(path)
      else:
         pfx = path
    return sorted_paths

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return { 'common_paths': common_paths }
```

then:

```
 - name: Filter
   set_fact:
       bar: "{{ foo | common_paths }}"
```

Test locally with:

```
---
 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Test data
      set_fact: 
        foo:
          - 'Lab01/'
          - 'Lab01/Ex5/'
          - 'Ex2/foo3/'
          - 'Ex2/foo2/'
          - 'Ex2/'
          - 'Lab03/Ex5/e/'
          - 'Lab02/y/z/Lab01/1/'
          - 'Lab02/y/z/Lab01/3/'
          - 'Lab01/Ex5/Lab02/'
          - 'Lab03/Ex5/d/1'

    - name: Filter
      set_fact: 
        bar: "{{ foo | common_paths }}"
```

Output:

```
$ ansible-playbook common_paths.yml  -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.10.4

PLAYBOOK: common_paths.yml *********************************************************************************
1 plays in common_paths.yml

PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Test data] *********************************************************************************    task path: /home/guido/Development/git/ansible-local/common_paths.yml:5
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "foo": [
            "Lab01/",
            "Lab01/Ex5/",
            "Ex2/foo3/",
            "Ex2/foo2/",
            "Ex2/",
            "Lab03/Ex5/e/",
            "Lab02/y/z/Lab01/1/",
            "Lab02/y/z/Lab01/3/",
            "Lab01/Ex5/Lab02/",
            "Lab03/Ex5/d/1/"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

TASK [Filter] *********************************************************************************
task path: /home/guido/Development/git/ansible-local/common_paths.yml:19
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "bar": [
            "Ex2/",
            "Lab01/",
            "Lab02/y/z/Lab01/1/",
            "Lab02/y/z/Lab01/3/",
            "Lab03/Ex5/d/1/",
            "Lab03/Ex5/e/"
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: I wonder if you add a complete runnable code for the plugin then it would be more helpful.  (still very good)

Comment: Perfect, really appreciate it - thank you! @guido